# JSON vs Array and is there a way to convert one to the other then back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I know in concept, or reality even they are essentially one in the same. However I know working with JSON objects (as of the time of writing this at least). That Altering the data within a given set of objects isn't the easiest thing. Of course I could be wrong, there could be an easy means of doing it all JSON. Which leads me to my actual question.

I am working almost entirely with JSON formatted Objects. Most of which I need to update frequently for storage for later use. Personally I would like to avoid sending data to and from the server to rebuild the JSON set of Objects every time. So I guess in all I am wondering if there is an equivalent to something like PHP's json_encode, json_decode? Either natively in JavaScript or through the jQuery Lib. and If not, how can I achieve something like that cause I feel (again at the moment) working with array's vs a JSON object is much easier (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: JSON and arrays are _not_ one in the same in concept or reality. JSON and objects aren't the same either. JSON is object data _serialised as a string_ that may or may not represent an array object. In JavaScript not all objects are arrays, and not all objects can be serialised to JSON. It is already easy to modify a JavaScript object's data: using an array only makes it easier where numeric indexes make sense. It isn't usual practice to modify JSON: you'd deserialise it and then work with the resulting object. Why do you feel a need to send data to and from the server to rebuild your objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why this question pops up in your mind is because you don't understand neither Javascript or JSON enough.

The Javascript array is always the numerical array. There is no associate array in JavaScript like the one you get in PHP using `json_decode(json, true);`. When people talking about associate array in JavaScript, they are in fact using JavaScript objects and it's properties, i.e.,

```
var my_so_called_array = {};

my_so_called_array['first_item'] = 'hello world';
alert(my_so_called_array['first_item']); // 'hello world'
alert(my_so_called_array.first_item); // also 'hello world'
```

One of the best about JSON is that the syntax is a subset of the object literal notation. That means JSON string itself is valid code for representing the "associate array" in Javascript. The "conversion" couldn't be simpler, just `eval()` the string as code will do:

```
var my_data = eval(json_string);
```

Or, use `jQuery.parseJSON()` or `JSON.parse()`:

```
var my_data = jQuery.parseJSON(json_string);

var my_data = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

The reason people prefer using `jQuery.parseJSON()` or `JSON.parse()` over `eval()` is because **eval is evil**:

1. It's slower
2. It doesn't check the validity of the JSON code, makes it suspect-able to injection attack.

Does the above explanation answer your question? You can find more information about JSON at www.json.org.

Answer (score 3):

All modern browsers support `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.

If you have to support older browsers, you can use jQuery's `$.parseJSON()`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @K.B I meant that `JSON.decode()` should be `JSON.parse()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: @Digital Plane: You're right. It's pretty late, and I wasn't thinking straight. Updated.